# Why are nerdfont icons differently sized in the same line?

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, fontconfig, dwm

I'm trying since quite a while to figure out, why these icons (see picture) are different in size. The status bar is dwmblocks by suckless (including simple bashscripts for the infos in the line) and I'm running arch.
[image: Inconsolata with diffrently sized icons]

I'm able to change the font from "Inconsolata" to some other font like "DejaVu", but that doesn't increase the symbols in size but rather adds some strange squares. [image: DejaVu with glitches] To increase the size, I tried to space the icons or exchange them in each script, but that had no effect.

Since I'm out of answers and ideas what to try, for fixing this, I'd need help on this.
What could be the reason for this kind of behavior and how to fix it?